# How to Convert String To Action in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I Send my method string names to MyFunction in other class as parameters in list.
now i want to use them like an action...how can i convert the name of them to actions.?

```
 public void MyFunction(List<string> Methodlist)
    {
        foreach (string Method in Methodlist)
        {
            Method(); 
        }
```

In Fact i'm sending my favorite methods names to my class for calling them
I used Reflection at first ... but I am assigning some values to public variables in my class..and when reflection make new instance all my data in public variables is lost.

Comment: If you want to execute those methods against another instance, you'll have to pass the instance you want to execute them against in. THEN you can reflect on it's type, find the methods and call them.

Comment: Whatever you're doing... don't.

Comment: `List<Action>` would be good here. Else you need to use reflection, but you need instances of type which holds methods anyway

Comment: You can call methods on existing instances of a class using reflection - There's no need to make a new instance.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You can pass lambdas or expressions instead of strings that look almost identical to strings, yet don't require reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public void MyFunction(List<string> methodlist)
{
    foreach (string methodName in methodlist)
    {
        this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(this, null);
    }
```

Or if you want to invoke them on another instance:

```
public void MyFunction(object instance, List<string> methodlist)
{
    foreach (string methodName in methodlist)
    {
        instance.GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(instance, null);
    }
```

Note that:

1) you should change `object` to the name of your type, I just put it there because you didn't provide the whole context

2) You shouldn't really be doing this - consider using [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) type instead, as suggested in comments and other answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can't only use the method name, because you're losing the instance of the object. Use :

```
public void MyFunction(List<Action> actions)
{
    foreach (Action action in actions)
    {
        action(); 
    }
```

If you're still sticking to the string as methodname, you should provide a instance object, also you do you know what parameters there are?

```
public void MyFunction(object instance, List<string> methodNames)
{
    Type instanceType = instance.GetType();

    foreach (string methodName in methodNames)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo = instanceType.GetMethod(methodName);

        // do you know any parameters??
        methodInfo.Invoke(instance, new object[] { });
    }
}
```

But I **wouldn't advise** such coding style!

Answer (score 1):

A `List<Action>` would be a better data type to execute some remote code. You can use reflection to get methods from their names, but you would also need the associated class instance and the method parameters.

Action:

```
var actionList= new List<Action>();

actionList.Add(() => SomeAwesomeMethod());
actionList.Add(() => foo.MyOtherAwesomeMethod());
actionList.Add(() => bar.ThisWillBeAwesome(foo));

foreach(var action in actionList)
{
    action();
}
```

See: [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx)

Reflection:

```
var methods = new List<string>();
methods.Add("SomeAwesomeMethod");

foreach(var item in methods)
{
    var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(item);
    method.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

See: [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use System.Reflection

Creat instance : 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx

Invok method : 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/a89hcwhh.aspx

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)